# Is there a way to sum or average properties in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a data grid control that I am using to show a lot of values like price, amount, daily change %, etc. So each cell shows the appropriate value.

These are all bound properties of the underlying data.

But some of the column headers I want to show the sum or the average of all these properties.

So for example for price, average(price), and so on.

Right now I had to create a separate class that does this for the entire collection and use these to bind to column headers but it does create a lot more code and extra layer to maintain.

Is this possible to do more elegantly, ideally in XAML? So I don't have to keep track of and raise changed events for the aggregated data.

Here is the code for a column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="50" SortMemberPath="PriceChangeMonthly.InPercent" local:AttachedClass.ColName="PriceChangeMonthly">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:MarketData.PriceChangeMonthlyDisplay)}"/>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <Grid>
                <TextBlock x:Name="ValueAvailable" Text="{Binding PriceChangeMonthly.Display}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Ellipse Width="6" Height="6" x:Name="ValueNotAvailable" Visibility="Hidden" Fill="#5a5a5a"/>
            </Grid>

            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PriceChangeMonthly.Display}" Value="-">
                    <Setter TargetName="ValueAvailable" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="ValueNotAvailable" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>

        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

PriceChangeMonthly.Display tracks the price change for each item.

MarketData.PriceChangeMonthlyDisplay sums and then averages these values for the entire collection.

```
public static decimal PriceChangeMonthly
{ get { return MarketData.CopiedCoins?.Where ( c => c.HasBalance ).Select ( c => c.PriceChangeMonthly.InPercent ).DefaultIfEmpty ( ).Average ( ) ?? 0; } }

public static string PriceChangeMonthlyDisplay
{
    get
    {
        decimal change = MarketData.PriceChangeMonthly;
        return String.Format ( "{0}{1:n1}%m", ( change >= 0 ) ? "+" : String.Empty, change );
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand your explanation.
Could you give an example of data calculation and/or a screenshot of the output DataGrid table.
First of all, I'm interested in whether the calculation depends only on the properties of this collection element, or there is a dependence on other elements.

Comment: Yes it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/KHgHlYW As you can all those values, I just average them all and show that average in the column header. They are not dependent on anything else.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then you need to get the average of the column elements in its header?
If so, then the decision critically depends on whether this value needs to be calculated one-time when specifying a collection, or whether this collection can change dynamically and the average needs to be calculated in real time.
Specify this nuance, please.

Comment: Yes basically what you said, and it has to update as the values are changing, so the header should always show the average value of its column elements.

Answer (score 1):

I created a universal converter to evaluate any expression.
My original theme: [ExpressionConverter](https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread2738784.html#post15045377).
Link to source code: [WpfMvvm/WpfMvvm.Converters](https://github.com/WpfMvvm/WpfMvvm.Converters)
Link to NuGet: [WpfMvvm.Converters](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WpfMvvm.Converters/)

### Translation of the original article:

ExpressionConverter - A converter that calculates simple arithmetic expressions.
To get a string expression from bindings in the converter, used the [Format(String, Object[]) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0#System_String_Format_System_String_System_Object___).
For a composite format string, either a converter parameter or the value of the first binding is used.
To calculate the resulting expression in a string, the [DataTable.Compute(String, String) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute?view=netframework-4.8) is used.
The first value is the received string with the expression, the second is the empty string.

The converter can be used as a normal converter for one value:

```xml
        <TextBlock Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Run Text="Half window height:"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding ActualHeight,
                                ElementName=window,
                                Mode=OneWay,
                                Converter={cnvs:ExpressionConverter},
                                ConverterParameter='{}{0} / 2.0'}"/>
        </TextBlock>
```

It can also be used as a multi-converter for several values:

```xml
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <x:Array Type="sys:String" x:Key="operators">
            <sys:String>+</sys:String>
            <sys:String>-</sys:String>
            <sys:String>/</sys:String>
            <sys:String>*</sys:String>
        </x:Array>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <UniformGrid Columns="1">
        <UniformGrid Columns="5" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBox x:Name="tb1" Text="1.2" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cBox" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                      ItemsSource="{DynamicResource operators}"
                      SelectedIndex="0"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="tb2" Text="3.4" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="=" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{cnvs:ExpressionConverter}"
                                  ConverterParameter="{}({0}) {1} ({2})">
                        <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tb1"/>
                        <Binding Path="SelectedItem" ElementName="cBox"/>
                        <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tb2"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </UniformGrid>
```

**P.S.** If you are interested in a similar method, I can show you how to use it for your task, if you provide more details about your task.

Comment: [CalcBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/calcbinding/info) not invented here

Answer (score 1):

I give the second answer, since I initially misunderstood the problem.

A proxy is implemented that monitors the specified property of the collection elements.
If their values change, or the collection changes, then all new values are passed to the Values property.

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace Converters
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(object[]))]
    public class ToArrayConverter : IValueConverter, IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            => new object[] { value };

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return values?.Clone();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public static ToArrayConverter Instance { get; } = new ToArrayConverter();
    }

    public class ToArrayConverterExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
            => ToArrayConverter.Instance;
    }
}
```

```cs
using Converters;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Proxy
{
    public class ObservingСollectionItemsProxy : Freezable
    {


        /// <summary>
        /// Indexed collection. Items in this collection will be observabled.
        /// </summary>
        public IList List
        {
            get { return (IList)GetValue(ListProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ListProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="List"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ListProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(List), typeof(IList), typeof(ObservingСollectionItemsProxy), new PropertyMetadata(null));



        /// <summary>
        /// The path to the property of the element, the value of which will be passed to the array of values.
        /// </summary>
        public string ValuePath
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ValuePathProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValuePathProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="ValuePath"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValuePathProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ValuePath), typeof(string), typeof(ObservingСollectionItemsProxy), new PropertyMetadata(null, PathChanged));

        private string privatePath;
        private static void PathChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ObservingСollectionItemsProxy proxy = (ObservingСollectionItemsProxy)d;
            proxy.privatePath = (string)e.NewValue;
            proxy.PathOrCountChanged();
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// An array of observed values.
        /// </summary>
        public IReadOnlyList<object> Values
        {
            get { return (IReadOnlyList<object>)GetValue(ValuesProperty); }
            private set { SetValue(ValuesPropertyKey, value); }
        }

        private static readonly IReadOnlyList<object> emptyArray = new object[0];

        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ValuesPropertyKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(nameof(Values), typeof(IReadOnlyList<object>), typeof(ObservingСollectionItemsProxy), new PropertyMetadata(emptyArray));
        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="Values"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValuesProperty = ValuesPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;




        /// <summary>Private property for creating binding to collection items.</summary>
        private static readonly DependencyProperty PrivateArrayProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("1", typeof(object[]), typeof(ObservingСollectionItemsProxy), new PropertyMetadata(null, ArrayChanged));

        private static void ArrayChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((ObservingСollectionItemsProxy)d).Values = (!(e.NewValue is object[] array) || array.Length == 0)
                ? emptyArray
                : Array.AsReadOnly(array);
        }

        /// <summary>A private property to monitor the number of items in the collection.</summary>
        private static readonly DependencyProperty PrivateCountProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("2", typeof(int?), typeof(ObservingСollectionItemsProxy), new PropertyMetadata(null, CountChanged));


        private int? privateCount;
        private static void CountChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ObservingСollectionItemsProxy proxy = (ObservingСollectionItemsProxy)d;
            proxy.privateCount = (int?)e.NewValue;
            proxy.PathOrCountChanged();
        }

        private void PathOrCountChanged()
        {
            MultiBinding multiBinding = new MultiBinding() { Converter = ToArrayConverter.Instance };
            if (privateCount != null && privateCount > 0)
            {
                string path = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(privatePath)
                    ? string.Empty
                    : $".{privatePath.Trim()}";
                for (int i = 0; i < privateCount.Value; i++)
                {
                    Binding binding = new Binding($"{nameof(List)}[{i}]{path}")
                    {
                        Source = this
                    };
                    multiBinding.Bindings.Add(binding);
                }
            }
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, PrivateArrayProperty, multiBinding);
        }

        public ObservingСollectionItemsProxy()
        {
            Binding binding = new Binding($"{nameof(List)}.{nameof(List.Count)}")
            {
                Source = this
            };
            _ = BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, PrivateCountProperty, binding);
        }

        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }

}
```

To process the resulting collection of values, you can use the converter

An example of a converter that receives a delegate in a parameter to a function that processes a value.
For this task, in order for the converter to process Values, the delegate parameter must be compatible with `IReadOnlyList<object>`.
That is, there can be one more of the following types: `IReadOnlyCollection<object>`, `IEnumerable<object>`, `IEnumerable`.

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace Converters
{
    public class FuncForValueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public static FuncForValueConverter Instance { get; } = new FuncForValueConverter();

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (parameter is Delegate func)
            {
                MethodInfo method = func.Method;

                Type retType = method.ReturnType;
                if (retType != null && retType != typeof(void))
                {
                    ParameterInfo[] parameters = method.GetParameters();
                    if (parameters.Length == 1)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            return func.DynamicInvoke(new object[] { value });
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        { }
                    }
                }
            }

            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


    }
    public class FuncForValueConverterExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
            => FuncForValueConverter.Instance;
    }
}
```

**Usage example.**

Helper classes: collection item type, collection type, set of functions.

```cs
using Simplified;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace ItemsProxyTest
{
    public class DoubleItem : BaseInpc
    {
        private double _number;

        public double Number { get => _number; set => Set(ref _number, value); }
    }

    public static class Function
    {
        public static readonly Func<IReadOnlyList<object>, double> Average 
            = (arr) => arr
            .OfType<double>()
            .Average();

        public static readonly Func<IReadOnlyList<object>, double> Sum
            = (arr) => arr
            .OfType<double>()
            .Sum();
    }

    public class DoubleItemCollection : ObservableCollection<DoubleItem>
    { }
}
```

XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Class="ItemsProxyTest.ItemsProxyTestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ItemsProxyTest"
        xmlns:proxy="clr-namespace:Proxy;assembly=Common"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:cnv="clr-namespace:Converters;assembly=Common"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ItemsProxyTestWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <local:DoubleItemCollection x:Key="list">
            <local:DoubleItem Number="123"/>
            <local:DoubleItem Number="456"/>
            <local:DoubleItem Number="789"/>
        </local:DoubleItemCollection>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{DynamicResource list}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Number}">
                    <DataGridColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <FrameworkElement.Resources>
                                    <proxy:ObservingСollectionItemsProxy
                                          x:Key="proxy"
                                          List="{DynamicResource list}"
                                          ValuePath="Number"/>
                                    <sys:String x:Key="str">121321</sys:String>
                                </FrameworkElement.Resources>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Values,
                                    Source={StaticResource proxy},
                                    Converter={cnv:FuncForValueConverter},
                                    ConverterParameter={x:Static local:Function.Average}}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Values,
                                    Source={StaticResource proxy},
                                    Converter={cnv:FuncForValueConverter},
                                    ConverterParameter={x:Static local:Function.Sum}}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```